# how can I change numbers in string?

Tags: java, lambda, char, java-stream

I need to replace each digit by its complement to 9 in given string **s**

Example: I have $**235**!  -> I have $(9-**2**)(9-**3**)(9-**5**)! -> I have $764!

```
public static void playPass(String s, int shift) {
        s.chars().map(i -> Character.isDigit(i) ? ____________?___________ : i)
                .mapToObj(i -> (char) i).forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Yes, of course, I can solve it by using for-loops, but I just want to know more about Streams.

So what I've tried:

1. `.map(i -> Character.isDigit(i) ? 9-i : i)`
   Output: "I have $ￗￖￔ!". It is because of the difference between char and representing it in integer.
2. `.map(i -> Character.isDigit(i) ? Character.getNumericValue(9-i) : i)` 
   Output: "I have $???!". But here I know that i - is not a real value, it is just ASCII code.
3. `.map(i -> Character.isDigit(i) ? Character.getNumericValue(9-Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(i))) : i)`
   Output: "I have $???!"

I guess that 3rd try is more clever, but it doesn't work(

I need some method (convertDigitCharToInt) which works like this (to change the char)

```
i - char

i = Character.getNumericValue(9-convertDigitCharToInt(i));
```

It is not a homework)) I'm just practicing in codewars.com. So there were a such problem.
[link]: https://codewars.com/kata/559536379512a64472000053/train/java)

Comment: Please read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: I wonder if you'd know how to finish this if you were told the answer is `9-i` .

Comment: It is not a homework)) I just practicing in **codewars.com**. So there were a such problem.(link: https://www.codewars.com/kata/559536379512a64472000053/train/java)

Comment: @AbandonedCrypt it does not work, I've tried it already

Comment: "Homework" and practice coding are essentially the same thing ... when they are the subject of a StackOverflow question.  You need to show us what you have done and ask a more specific question ... rather than just asking us to give you a solution.

Comment: Yes - AbandonedCrypt's answer is not exactly correct.  But it contains a big clue.  You asked: *"How can I solve this problem?"*  The way to solve this is to think about it.  Start with researching what exactly is the `char` type, what does it represent, and *how* does it represent it?

Comment: @АлинурЖенис it does not work because you have to do a last thing to it, there's multiple ways to do it but as a last hint, one of them has to do with getting the 'value of' something

Answer (score 0):

You have almost done it.  The complement is calculated as the difference between character `'9'` and a current character digit *plus* shift by `'0'` to get a new character.

The following code works fine:

```java
public static void playPass(String s) {
        s.chars()
            .map(i -> Character.isDigit(i) ? '9' - i + '0' : i)
            .mapToObj(i -> (char) i)
            .forEach(System.out::print);
}
```

Test:

```
playPass("I have $235");   // I have $764
```